# Get timezone and date of browser from date object

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have this date object in javascript.

```
var d = new Date();
```

The above line of code will be run on Chrome browser. I would like to extract information like the date (example: 14-Dec-2016) and timezone(example: GMT+0800) of the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it something like this :

```
var now = new Date();

document.write(now.toUTCString() + "<br>")
document.write(now.toTimeString() + "<br>")
```

Some of the other properties are :

```
toDateString()  Converts the date portion of a Date object into a readable string
toGMTString()   Deprecated. Use the toUTCString() method instead
toISOString()   Returns the date as a string, using the ISO standard
toJSON()    Returns the date as a string, formatted as a JSON date
toLocaleDateString()    Returns the date portion of a Date object as a string, using locale conventions
toLocaleTimeString()    Returns the time portion of a Date object as a string, using locale conventions
toLocaleString()    Converts a Date object to a string, using locale conventions
toString()  Converts a Date object to a string
toTimeString()  Converts the time portion of a Date object to a string
toUTCString() Converts a Date object to a string, according to universal time
```

Also you can even use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) plugin to help you out with this. It makes all these tasks trivial.

Also to get the timezone offset, use something like :

```
getTimezoneOffset();
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset), `getTimezoneOffset` should be able to get you the timezone.

```
var d = new Date();
d.getTimezoneOffset(); // returns offset in minutes
```

As for formatting the date, [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a pre-existing library that makes date and time formatting much, much less painful than it needs to be with great cross-browser support.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
```

Or this:

```
if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function now() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  };
}
```